# What does the comma in sed commands stand for?

Tags: sed

What does the following command mean:

```
sed -e '/SUBCKT\ REDBK128S4_LC/,/ENDS/ d'   $1
```

What does `,` stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you specify two addresses, then you specify range of lines over which the command is executed. In your `sed` expression, it deletes all lines beginning with the line matched by the first pattern and up to and including the line matched by the second pattern.

Answer (score 12):

It specifies a `RANGE` over which to apply the `d` command.

Ranges can be specified with patterns like this:

```
sed -e '/START/,/END/ command'    # apply command on lines between START and END pattern
```

or with line numbers like this:

```
sed -e '1,35 command'    # apply command on lines 1 to 35
```

or with a mixture, like this:

```
sed '1200,$ {/abc/ command}'     # apply command on lines 1200 to end of file that contain "abc"
```